# Probability model vs statistical model vs stochastic model

Tags: modeling

I understand that a statistical model is a model which accounts for the uncertainty in the model. Eg. Demand price equation: $demand_{i}= a+b price_{i}+ u_{i}$ where $u_{i}$ refers to the residual term.

How to differentiate the other two models from a statistical model?

Answer (score 4):

Many times there is observable phenomena that is random in nature. We call it a **Random Process** (Random **Experiment**). The random process has outcomes, and subsets of these outcomes are called events. We map these events to a numeric form using **Random Variables**.

We study and capture our knowledge about this random process by creating a **Stochastic Model**. The stochastic model predicts the output of an event by (1) providing different choices (of values of a random variable) AND (2) the probability of those choices. These two elements are summarized as a **Probability Distribution**.

This distribution has some parameters (like mean, standard deviation) which were inferred from the observable phenomena using **Statistical Inference**.

Before inference, the distribution had unknown (not inferred yet) parameters. It was, hence, a family of distributions, since each value of the parameter is a different distribution. This family is called a **Statistical Model**.

Usually a statistical model is guessed (exponential, binomial, normal, uniform, bernoulli, etc) using **Exploratory Data Analysis**, then its parameters are **inferred** (estimated) by applying statistical inference (say, algorithms involving loss function minimization) to arrive at a stochastic model (statistical model with known parameters) (a.k.a. **Estimator**) that captures our knowledge about the random process.

The term '**Probability Model**' (probabilistic model) is usually an alias for stochastic model.

References:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4268o.png) Using statistical methods to model the fine-tuning of molecular machines and systems
Steinar Thorvaldsen, Ola Hossjer

[2] Statistics (Point Estimation) - Lecture One Charlotte Wickham - Berkeley

[image: Stochastic Model and Statistical Model]